# Definition of polynomial ring with arbitrarily many variables

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I have seen a lot of posts in StackExchange regarding polynomial rings with arbitrarily many variables, but I have not seen a complete definition and construction of this ring in one place.

Hence I am posting the following questions:

1. Let $X$ be a non-empty set, and $R$ be a commutative ring with 1. What is the definition of $R[X]$ ?
2. How do I construct this ring? And does this construction involve Axiom of Choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bourbakist language with which you may be most familiar, $R[X]=R$ is the set of almost-everywhere-zero functions $p:SX\to R,$ where $SX$ is the set of almost-everywhere-zero functions $X\to\mathbb N.$ Note that $SX$ is a commutative monoid under pointwise addition. The ring structure on $R[X]$ comes from the pointwise addition but has a nontrivial multiplication operation, using the monoid structure on $SX:$ we have $pq(m)=\sum_{m_1m_2=m} p(m_1)q(m_2).$ The sum is in $R,$ while the product under the sum is in $SX.$ The sum is guaranteed to be finite by the restriction that $p,q$ are almost everywhere (that is, for all but finitely many values) zero.

Concretely, of course, the elements of $SX$ are monomials with variables from $X$ and the elements of $R[X]$ are linear combinations of these with coefficients from $R.$ The Bourbakist-style definition slightly obscured this view. More abstractly, $R[X]$ is the free $R$-algebra generated by $SX$, while $SX$ is the free commutative monoid generated by $X.$ Composing, $R[X]$ is the free $R$-algebra generated by $X.$ The existence of such free constructions is a basic application of the general adjoint functor theorem. Then one can see that the relevant categories are finitarily monadic over the category of sets, and prove that free constructions for all such monads consist of all terms expressible in terms of the generating set and the basic operations provided by the monad. That’s probably closer to how we really think about polynomials in practice.

This particular setting can also be handled very well with model theory, rather than category theory, where we’re talking about some varieties of algebras and what’s directly axiomatized is a *term*, so that one can simply prove that the free $R$-algebra generated by $X$ is the set of all terms of the theory of $R$-algebras with constants drawn from $X.$

As you can see, the axiom of choice is not implicated in any of these definitions.